# How to connect Jasper Report to an OpenEdge application

Tags: jasper-reports, openedge, progress-4gl

I am trying to integrate Jasper reporting in my application which currently uses Crystal Report. As of now I am able to connect to the Progress DB and able to publish report to the jasper server from the studio.
The next step is to view these report from my application in pdf format.

Any help on how to do this or best suggestion would be highly appreciable. Is there any JasperConverter in Progress to convert the JRXML files to pdf directly from application?

Thanks Ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking in the wrong place. Shouldn't you be running the Jasper Report Viewer to view the report?

To invoke that from a Progress 4GL session you would either shell out and run an OS command or invoke a DLL. The details depend on the version of Progress and the platform that your client session is running on.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, I used the API call to the JasperServer to preview the pdf file in my application as there is no Runtime Application for Jasper Report as compared to Crystal, as far as I know.

Comment: Using an API call sounds a lot like invoking a DLL.